# Android Exception: UnknownFormatConversionException

Tags: android, exception, format

Hi I am setting some text inside a RobotoText that is positioned inside of a ViewHolder I am calling it like this:

```
viewHolder.txtSimilarAds.setText((((Property)  ads.get(position)).getSimilar_items_count() == 1 ? context.getString(R.string.ad_data_similar)  : context.getString(R.string.ad_data_similar_plural, ads.get(position).getImagesCount())));
```

However (sometimes NOT always)for some reason I keep getting this error exception UnknownFormatConversionException and it points to this line inside of the class. What could be the problem? Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the string in `R.string.ad_data_similar_plural` contains a valid placeholder for an integer. It should be something like `"Here is my number: %d"`.

[String format specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

---

As an aside, one-liner like these are harder to understand, and make debugging more difficult. A more readable approach would have given the erroneous line more easily:

```
String similarAdsText;
Property adsProperty = ads.get(position);

if (adsProperty.getSimilar_items_count() == 1) {
    similarAdsText = context.getString(R.string.ad_data_similar);
}
else {
    similarAdsText = context.getString(R.string.ad_data_similar_plural, adsProperty.getImagesCount());
}

viewHolder.txtSimilarAds.setText(similarAdsText);
```

Comment: Yes I agree with you! Your suggested approach makes goods sense. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying too many methods in single line try splitting it. The problem looks like you are comparing `Property` object with 1 which is wrong.

```
(Property)ads.get(position)).getSimilar_items_count() == 1

change this to

Property property = (Property)  ads.get(position));
property.getSimilar_items_count() == 1
```

Comment: hmm you are suggesting I missed a ")" and it bugs out?